# JavaCV FFMpegRecorder streams video not displayed properly

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, javacv

I have been in loop for 5 days trying to implement JavaCV with FFmpegRecorder, Having figured out that i have to use OpenCvFrameConverter to conert IplImage to frame, I finally managed to see some video over the stream. but now the problem seems to be that the audio works perfect and clearly, but video is not displayed properly.

[image]

Beside that there is a massive delay on the stream, well over 40sec, when i thought RTMP had 2-4sec delay,

Here is some code:

**FFmpegFrameRecorder Initialization**

```
recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, screenWidth, screenHeight, 1);
    recorder.setFormat("flv");
    recorder.setSampleRate(44100);
    recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_FLV1);// AV_CODEC_ID_FLV1
    recorder.setVideoOption("preset", "ultrafast"); 
    recorder.setFrameRate(30);
```

**And here is my SurfaceChanged and PreviewFrame Methods**

```
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = camParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();         

        android.hardware.Camera.Size z = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        int imageWidth = z.width;
        int imageHeight = z.height;
        camParams.setPreviewSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);
        mCamera.setParameters(camParams);

        for(int[] arr : camParams.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange()){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Supported range: " + arr[0] + " - " + arr[1]);
        }

        Camera.Parameters framerateAttempts = mCamera.getParameters();
        camParams.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Preview Framerate: " + camParams.getPreviewFrameRate());
        Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
        {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
        {
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
        {
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
        {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        }
        camParams.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        mCamera.setParameters(framerateAttempts);

        startPreview();
    }

 @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        /* get video data */
        if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
            yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Writing Frame");
            try {
                long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                    recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                }

                OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converterToMat = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
                Frame f = converterToMat.convert(yuvIplimage);
                recorder.record(f);
            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```